How Azure Container App resource configuration works?
When we add resource configuration like 4 CPU and 8 Gi memory while deploying container to the Azure Container Apps, what does it means ? (Note: Using Dedicated Plan)
My doubt is, is this resource configuration is a limit for container, that it cannot use beyond 4 CPU and 8 Gi memory or it is a minimum resource allocation to the container and it can use if it require more CPU or Memory?

When you add resource configuration like 4 CPU and 8 Gi memory while deploying a container to Azure Container Apps using the Dedicated Plan, it means that these are the maximum resources allocated to the container. The container cannot use beyond 4 CPU and 8 Gi memory.

The number of CPUs allocated is the maximum amount of CPU the container can use. It's measured in "CPU units," where 1 CPU unit is equivalent to 1 vCPU/Core of compute capacity and the memory allocation is the maximum amount of RAM the container can use. For the Dedicated Plan in Azure Container Apps, the resources you define will be allocated from your dedicated infrastructure, but the same rules apply: these are still the limits, not the reservations.
If your container tries to exceed these limits, it may be throttled (in the case of CPU) or terminated (in the case of memory). If you need your container to have more resources, you'd need to configure your container app with higher limits.
References:

Containers in Azure Container Apps - Configuration

